# Magento v1.9.2.1 Products Table

Tags: mysql, magento

I need to get specific data from the database tables in Magento v1.9.2.1 I'm able to find the product tables but I'm not sure where to find specific data.

I have a desktop application that needs to display the exact same data when you view a particular product in Magento

These are the data I am looking for in the Magento Database - SKU, Product Title, Price, Images, Short Description, Long Description

I'm having a hard time understanding its database structure. I'd really appreciate if anyone can help me look for the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you to get started. I use LINQPad to be able to code c# against my Magneto database. It lets me write some high level code against the database but still see the underlying queries that get generated.

I have a query that produces this result for me:

```
+-----+-----+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| sku | qty | price | special_price | special_from_date | special_to_date |
+-----+-----+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
| X1  |   5 | 13.99 | 8.99          | 2015-04-19 00:00  |                 |
| X2  |  12 | 10.99 | 7.99          | 2015-04-19 00:00  |                 |
| X3  |   9 | 9.99  | 5.99          | 2015-04-19 00:00  |                 |
+-----+-----+-------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Here's the (slightly simplified) c# query for this data:

```
var items =
    from x in catalog_product_entity
    join stock in cataloginventory_stock_item on x.entity_id equals stock.product_id
    join price in catalog_product_entity_decimal.Where(_ => _.attribute_id == 75 && _.store_id == 0) on x.entity_id equals price.entity_id into prices
    join special_price in catalog_product_entity_decimal.Where(_ => _.attribute_id == 76 && _.store_id == 0) on x.entity_id equals special_price.entity_id into special_prices
    join special_from_date in catalog_product_entity_datetime.Where(_ => _.attribute_id == 77 && _.store_id == 0) on x.entity_id equals special_from_date.entity_id into special_from_dates
    join special_to_date in catalog_product_entity_datetime.Where(_ => _.attribute_id == 78 && _.store_id == 0) on x.entity_id equals special_to_date.entity_id into special_to_dates
    select new
    {
        x.sku,
        stock.qty,
        prices,
        special_prices,
        special_from_dates,
        special_to_dates,
    };
```

This produces these actual SQL calls to the DB:

```
SELECT t2.entity_id, t2.attribute_id, t2.entity_type_id, t2.store_id, t2.value, t2.value_id
FROM catalog_product_entity AS t0
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_id = t1.product_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS t2
  ON (((t2.attribute_id = 75) AND (t2.store_id = 0)) AND (t2.entity_id = t0.entity_id))

SELECT t2.entity_id, t2.attribute_id, t2.entity_type_id, t2.store_id, t2.value, t2.value_id
FROM catalog_product_entity AS t0
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_id = t1.product_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal AS t2
  ON (((t2.attribute_id = 76) AND (t2.store_id = 0)) AND (t2.entity_id = t0.entity_id))

SELECT t2.entity_id, t2.attribute_id, t2.entity_type_id, t2.store_id, t2.value, t2.value_id
FROM catalog_product_entity AS t0
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_id = t1.product_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime AS t2
  ON (((t2.attribute_id = 77) AND (t2.store_id = 0)) AND (t2.entity_id = t0.entity_id))

SELECT t2.entity_id, t2.attribute_id, t2.entity_type_id, t2.store_id, t2.value, t2.value_id
FROM catalog_product_entity AS t0
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_id = t1.product_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime AS t2
  ON (((t2.attribute_id = 78) AND (t2.store_id = 0)) AND (t2.entity_id = t0.entity_id))

SELECT t0.sku, t1.qty, t0.entity_id
FROM catalog_product_entity AS t0
INNER JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_id = t1.product_id)
```

Now, you do need to know what the `attribute_id` values are for your database.

I use this c# query for that:

```
var query =
    from et in eav_entity_type
    where et.entity_model == "catalog/product"
    join a in eav_attribute on et.entity_type_id equals a.entity_type_id
    select new
    {
        a.attribute_id,
        a.attribute_code,
        a.backend_type
    };
```

Which translates to this SQL:

```
SELECT t1.attribute_id, t1.attribute_code, t1.backend_type
FROM eav_entity_type AS t0
INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS t1
  ON (t0.entity_type_id = t1.entity_type_id)
WHERE (t0.entity_model = @p0)
-- p0 = [catalog/product]
```

That gives me this kind of result:

```
+--------------+------------------------+--------------+
| attribute_id |     attribute_code     | backend_type |
+--------------+------------------------+--------------+
|          108 | category_ids           | static       |
|           92 | color                  | int          |
|           79 | cost                   | decimal      |
|          117 | country_of_manufacture | varchar      |
|          115 | created_at             | static       |
|          103 | custom_design          | varchar      |
|          104 | custom_design_from     | datetime     |
|          105 | custom_design_to       | datetime     |
|          106 | custom_layout_update   | text         |
|           72 | description            | text         |
+--------------+------------------------+--------------+
```

You then use the backend-type to produce the `LEFT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity_datetime AS t2 ON (((t2.attribute_id = 78)` snippits of SQL.